# std::equal_range with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

Lets say I have a vector of strings and I want to find all strings, that start with `'a'`, so I can do this:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()( const std::string &s, char c ) const { return s.front() < c; }
    bool operator()( char c, const std::string &s ) const { return s.front() < c; }
};
std::vector<std::string> strings;
...
std::sort( strings.begin(), strings.end() );
auto range = std::equal_range( strings.begin(), strings.end(), 'a', cmp{} );
...
```

This method is error prone, as it is easy to make mistake (for example I think it should be `c < s.front()` in second method) and has code duplication.

So is it possible to implement comparison function with generic lambda instead of structure with 2 methods?

More generic question, why value to compare has to be passed as argument to `std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound` and `std::equal_range` when it can easily be captured by lambda or passed to comparison structure, and then this issue will not be there at all?

How it could work if `std::equal_range` would not require value?

```
struct cmp {
    cmp( char lc ) : c( lc ) {}
    bool operator()( const std::string &s ) const { return s.front() < c; }
    char c;
};
std::vector<std::string> strings;
...
std::sort( strings.begin(), strings.end() );
auto range = std::equal_range( strings.begin(), strings.end(), cmp{'a'} );
```

Comment: If you are willing to pass `"a"` in place of `'a'`, then a lambda taking two strings and comparing their first characters would work. Otherwise, a named class with two overloads looks like the cleanest solution to me. Note though that the second overload, as currently written, does its comparison the wrong way round.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that's obvious, but it could be not string, but an object, which sorted by part of it, so I do not want to create whole object just for use it as a key.

Comment: You can use `std::partition_point`.

Comment: @T.C. can you provide an example as answer? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lower_bound` is

```
std::partition_point(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
                     [](const auto& s) { return s.front() < 'a'; });
```

`upper_bound` is

```
std::partition_point(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
                     [](const auto& s) { return s.front() <= 'a'; });
```

Yes, that means you have to write two calls to get the equivalent of `equal_range`. You can wrap this into a free template:

```
template<class Iter, class T, class Proj>
std::pair<Iter, Iter> my_equal_range(Iter first, Iter last, const T& value, Proj proj) {
    auto b = std::partition_point(first, last, [&](const auto& s) { return proj(s) < value; });
    auto e = std::partition_point(b, last, [&](const auto& s) { return !(value < proj(s)); });
    return {b, e};
}
```

And call it as

```
my_equal_range(strings.begin(), strings.end(), 'a',
               [](const auto& s) { return s.front(); });
```

---

The Ranges TS working draft adds projections to algorithms, so you will (eventually) be able to do this:

```
std::experimental::ranges::equal_range(strings, 'a', {},
                                       [](const auto& s) { return s.front(); });
```

Comment: Would it be more effective for second `std::partition_point` call to use output of previous call instead of `first`?

Comment: @Slava Sure, that would be more efficient.

Comment: you can actually reuse `first` and `last` :) `first = ...; last = ...; return {first,last};`

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question whether the comparator can be implemented using a generic lambda, yes, it can. You'll also need a couple of helper functions to return the desired result given a `char` or `string` argument.

```
auto get_char(char c)               { return c; }
auto get_char(std::string const& s) { return s.front(); }
auto cmp = [](auto const& l, auto const& r) { return get_char(l) < get_char(r); };
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1074fe84b5d448df)

---

One reason you cannot simply have the comparator capture the value is because the two overloads of [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) could then be ambiguous, you'd need a slightly different name or some other way (for instance, a tag argument) to disambiguate the two.

Comment: Good solution, but not perfect :( It has the same issue that stopped me from using algorithms before lambda - you have to write functors outside of scope of code where it is used.